# how to find a jquery or pure javascript associated with a class or div or any other elements in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html

I was wondering if there is any way to find all the scripts associated with a particular element in web page.

That is if there is a photo, and there is two attached jquery function like on mouse over and on click, I need to get details of this functions without looking onto entire script.

Comment: The next UX revolution after touch: Lick screens! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is with a bookmarklet called [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)

Comment: That looks pretty cool.  Exactly the kinda thing I tried to build... and sounds like they're running into the same types of issues (IE for instance).

Comment: It is nice, but AFAIK, it doesn't, and can't, tell you about event handlers attached with native JS. Only those attached via libraries that support such a goal, or "on{event-type}" attributes in HTML. If the code is your own, then the solution is simply to use one such library and/or write your own wrapper functions for attaching events and use them exclusively. To also track handlers created by 3rd party code, you might overload the native JS function or modify it's prototype and make sure the relevant code is run before the 3rd party code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an easy way.  I spent a few days trying to write an augmentation wrapper/extension that would track all even assignment in page and thus allow for inspection of such - the problem is that it requires tweaking for each library, and iirc wasn't useful if any native event assignment was used.

This is exactly the reason there needs to be well organized code, and remembering that "unobtrusive" doesn't mean "incomprehensible" - try to keep all your event assignments well organized and easily associated/found for a particular element.